# Is it true that a neural network with many layers converges to a solution?

Tags: neural-network

For one hidden layer exist Universal approximation theorem by  George Cybenko.

But for multi layers net converges result is stohastic or determ and guaranteed as one hidden layer net?
And is there an appropriate proof?

Comment: The universal approximation theorem makes no guarantees about  convergence to a solution. Just that a limited approximation can be *constructed* in theory for any function.

Comment: Ok, that's my mistake. But besides a Convergence theorem exist, i'm right?